# What should a developer take into consideration when writing code in order to make it easier for a tester to automate tests with selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, automation

All I think of is writing the code from a tester's perspective. Having id or name for buttons and fields. Should anything else matter to make automation easier?
I am at the beginning of my career as a tester and I need to know what to request from the developers.

Comment: not just having id's, but having *unique* id's is what is important.

Comment: ...and id attributes must be unique: https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#concept-id

Answer (score 0):

A few tips:

1. Put an [unique] ID where you can.
2. Make use of the data-* attributes. This allows QA to find elements using relevant data.
3. Avoid "divitus". This makes for brittle selectors.
4. Make event triggers known. I have filled out a form but the submit button wouldn't enable until I asked my dev and he explained that I needed to trigger the blur event.
5. Use the automation. You don't have to fix the issues, but you can alert the QA person that your feature introduces false positives until the tests are updated.
6. Write Unit Tests (not UI Tests) for your project.